# Are repeated backgrounds in html more efficient if they are larger than 1px?

Tags: html, css, performance, web

If there is a one-dimensional background that is repeated on a certain dimension, is there any mentionable difference in performance if the image is e.g. 1px wide versus 10 or 20 pixels wide?

Comment: Good question. I've never used 1px wide images, and in my experience the filesize doesn't become much larger, so I don't see why I should not use 10px images.

Comment: Someone here http://forums.devshed.com/css-help-116/background-repeat-efficiency-276824.html is quoted as saying:

Comment: "This is a subject I've given a very superficial study. The thing to consider is the tare weight of the server response header and the image's own header. For example, a 1×1 jpg (GIMP generated) of solid color #808080 is file size 334 bytes. At 200×5, the file size is 352 bytes. For an 18 byte increase ((352 + server header size) ÷ (334 + server header size) × 100 = percent increase in bandwidth), client tiling load is reduced by three orders of magnitude.

My own opinion is that there is no significant benefit gained by reducing the image file size to less than 1KB. YMMV."

Comment: My personal, completely non-scientific opinion, is that both numbers are so small that I don't care and just use the smallest possible image because that is conceptually simpler for me. The "efficiency" to consider here is coding/design efficiency, not computational efficiency.

Comment: from Nokia: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices#Avoid_background-repeat_if_the_background-image_is_small_relative_to_its_containing_element

Comment: @Gerben Nice link... I suppose the difference would be more on the side of rendering for mobile devices so that'd be something to consider.  If it's not much of a difference, better off going without the repeating.

Comment: I agree with Shawn. On an early android web app I worked on, not having a background image at all made a huge difference for scrolling around the page on low end phones especially, as there was no need to buffer an image that isn't there, and isn't tiled repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean a two-dimensional background.

I can't imagine that there is any noticeable difference, on modern computers.  However, because bandwidth is still at a premium, especially on mobile devices, I think you would be better off conserving bandwidth by repeating a 1px wide image instead of say 2 or 3 px wide.

UPDATE: We just ran a test, unscientifically, but certainly perceptually relevant, in which one page rendered a 10px green square over a 10,000,000px square div, and another page rendered a 1px green square over the same size div.  All styles are set with CSS, both pages had no other content.  The graphics were loaded locally.  There was absolutely no perceptual difference in the rendering in either Safari 5 for Mac, or FireFox 8 for Mac.  Still, it's possible that there could be performance issues on certain models of older (crappier) smart phones.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Greg! ;) Well of course all images are technically two-dimensional, what I meant by one dimensional is that the image only varies on one dimension, and thus the width (or height) of the other dimensional is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not going to notice a difference between a 1px wide versus 20px wide background image, although there will be one.  It's just the difference in file size that you have to download that you'd see.  The larger the image, the larger the file size most likely, so it would take a fraction longer to initially download.  Once it's in place you won't notice a difference either way.